# How can I pass a Cognito Principal Id to Integration Request Header with AWS API Gateway?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have a Method that is using a Cognito User Pools Authorizer.   I'm wanting to grab the principal Id from the context and pass to the integration endpoint via a custom header.   I've tried context.authorizer.principalId which yields nothing. i.e the header doesn't show.  If I set to a 'hardCodedString' it will show.  Other context options like appId are working, seems specific to Cognito.

Essentially I'm attempting to have API Gateway handle the token validation part of the work.

Comment: Were you trying to work with HTTP Integrations rather than Lambda? I realize this was forever ago but I have a similar question, but specific to HTTP integrations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved via using header attribute in integration like:

context.authorizer.claims.email
and 
context.authorizer.claims.sub

within the Method's Integration Request settings of API Gateway.